# shell function definition with and without keyword

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

It took me forever to find out that the reason the following piece of shell script doesn't work:

```
if command -v z > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    unalias z 2> /dev/null

    z() {
        [ $# -gt 0 ] && _z "$*" && return
            cd "$(_z -l 2>&1 |
                fzf --height 40% --nth 2.. --reverse --inline-info +s --tac \
                --query "${*##-* }" |
                sed 's/^[0-9,.]* *//')"
    }
fi
```

is that the function definition, in this case, requires the function keyword, `function z() {...}`.
Without it I get:

```
~/.shell/functions:112: defining function based on alias `z'
~/.shell/functions:112: parse error near `()'
```

I couldn't find anywhere that says there is any difference between using or not using the `function` keyword in a function definition. Why is that the solution in this case?
(I tried in zsh and in bash)

Comment: Why do you want `z()` in that place anyway?

Comment: I want to override the z alias to use the function which 'enhances' it with fzf. Yet I want to check the z is actually installed before that.

Comment: Ain't that `alias z=...`then? Sorry, my bash knowledge is a bit old.

Comment: Why don't you just do: `unalias z 2> /dev/null` and then declare the function. No `if` statements needed.

Comment: Because I would end up defining the z() function even if z isn't installed, which is what I'm trying to avoid with the check.

Comment: @Fuoco: Are you trying to define a function inside an if conditional

Comment: The point is, defining a function inside of an if conditional appears to work, most of the time, yet it breaks with this strange error message in that case.
I'm doing similar kinds of checks in other places and there is no problem. The difference here is only that before the if conditional 'z' is actually an alias and not just a binary.

Comment: @Inian: Yes. I couldn't find out whether it's legal or not so I just tried, and it actually works.

Comment: BTW, `function z() {` is generally best avoided. The `function` keyword exists for compatibility with old extended ksh syntax, `function z {` (which had several behavior changes when this syntax was in use, such as making variables function-local by default; note that bash *doesn't* do that even when `function` is in use), whereas the format with parens is for compatibility with POSIX sh, `z() {`; when you combine the two, you get something that isn't compatible with old ksh, and *also* isn't compatible with POSIX sh. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete for more discussion.

Comment: You could just use `if unalias z 2> /dev/null; then` which would simplify (but it would not change your problem).

Comment: Aliases are different from functions. If you want to unset an alias use `unalias name_of_alias`. If you want to un-define a function, use `unset name_of_function`.

Answer (score 8):

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.

`z` is therefore expanded when the `if` statement is read, **not** when it is executed. So even if you `unalias`, the aliases are already expanded in your `if` statement (namely `z() ...` is expanded).

Adding `function` helps because aliases are expanded **only** when they are used as the first word. If you add `function` to your function declaration, nothing gets expanded.

---

Check this code that demonstrates the behavior of aliases inside a compound command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias greet='echo hello'

if true; then
    unalias greet 2> /dev/null

    #still outputs hello!
    greet  
    #not first word, outputs greet
    echo greet                                  
fi

#error!
greet
```

This snippet shows that the alias `foo` really gets expanded before execution. As a result, there is a function called `bar` declared, **not** `foo`:

```
$ alias foo='bar'
$ foo() { echo hello; }
$ declare -f foo
$ declare -f bar
bar () 
{ 
    echo hello
}

#declaring with 'function' keyword will work as expected
$ function foo { echo hi; }
$ declare -f foo 
foo () 
{ 
    echo hi
}
```

---

[Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) explains the behavior of aliases in further detail and recommends the following:

> To be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line, and do
>   not use alias in compound commands.

Comment: I think you're confusing functions and aliases. They are different.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I disagree. Please read the answer again and tell me in what ways didn't it answer the question and in what ways does it confuse functions and aliases. There were both discussed because they were both related to the question, that's all.

Comment: @DeanHouseholder Aliases are actually closely connected to functions here as function is a compound command and their use together can cause unintuitive behavior. The answer provided examples and explanation of such behavior.

Comment: The original example doesn't contain any aliases. Only functions. Yet line 2 is trying to use `unalias` to remove the definition of the function which will produce an error.

A function can only be removed by `unset`.

The only time you need to use the keyword `function` to declare a bash function is when you already have an actual alias defined with the same name.

Your example correctly demonstrates this. Sorry to downvote you. If you edit your answer I'll be allowed to upvote you.

Comment: @DeanHouseholder no problem, just wanted to know whether I gave some misinformation and should edit my answer :) have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Man page (man bash) states "The reserved word function is optional.":

Shell Function Definitions
       A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command and executes a compound command with a new set of positional parameters.  Shell functions are declared as follows:

```
   name () compound-command [redirection]
   function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
          This  defines a function named name.  **The reserved word function is optional.**  If the function reserved word is supplied, the parentheses are optional.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was referring to. So why is it that in this case it is not optional?

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see what you meant.

Comment: It's optional in the sense that you can always define a function without the keyword. What the name of that function will *be* may depend on alias expansion.